# Continuity in Topological Spaces: Understanding a Theorem

Tags: general-topology

Theorem. 3.9: Suppose $f:(X,d)\rightarrow(Y,\rho)$
  is a function from one pseudometric space into another. Then $f$
  is continuous only if it is true that $\forall x\in X,\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$
  such that $d(x,y)<\delta\implies\rho(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$
 .

Proof. Suppose $f$
  is continuous. The cell/ball centered at $f(x)$
  of radius $\epsilon$
  denoted $B(f(x),\epsilon)$
  is open, and thus its inverse image is also open (By theorem 3.5), and contains $x$
  (by definition of inverse image). Thus 
  for every $y\in C(x,\delta)$, we have $f(y)\in B(f(x),\epsilon)$. $\square$

The statement of the theorem is confusing to me. In the text, continuity is only defined for functions between topological spaces $ f:(X,\mathbf{T})\rightarrow(Y,\mathbf{V})$. Between which two topological spaces is $f$ continuous in the theorem?

From the logic of the proof it seems that the theorem means to say $f$ must be continuous between $f:(X,\mathbf{T})\rightarrow(Y,\mathbf{V})$ where $\mathbf{T},\mathbf{V}$ are the topolgies generated by $d,\rho$ respectivley (as otherwise we wouldn't be guaranteed that $B(f(x),\epsilon)$ is open in $(Y,\mathbf{V})$, as stated in the first line of the proof). Is this correct?

Comment: yes. If you have a (pseudo-)metric space and talk about it in topological term, then it is implicitly understood that the spaces are equipped with the topologies induced by their (pseudo-)metrics. So in this sense every metric space is a topological space. (But *not* every topological space is a metric space).

Comment: In many beginner courses in analysis, "continuity" is defined using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ precisely in the sense of your question. So this definition only works for metric spaces. Then later, general topology in introduced and continuity is re-defined in terms of open sets. The Theorem of your question is very important because it shows that these two definitions are in fact equivalent.

Comment: @Simon "it is implicitly understood that the spaces are equipped with the topologies induced by their (pseudo-)metrics." Thank you. I did not realize this, and while I was able to deduce it, it is great to get confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed if $f:(X,d) \rightarrow (Y,\rho)$ is a function between pseudometric spaces, then all topological notions are considered between the topological spaces $(X,\mathscr{T}_d)$ and $(Y, \mathscr{T}_\rho)$ (the smallest topologies generated by the open balls in the respective pseudometric. That's the reason the proof works, as you correctly note. So being continuous w.r.t. the generated topologies implies being $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-continuous. The reverse also holds, suppose $f$ is $\varepsilon-\delta$ continuous, and suppose $O \subseteq Y$ is open.  To see that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, take $x \in f^{-1}[O]$. Then $f(x) \in O$, and is $O$ is open, there is some $\varepsilon >0$, such that $B_\rho(f(x), \varepsilon) \subseteq O$. Pick $\delta >0$ for $x$ and $\varepsilon$. Then $B_d(x,\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$, if you unwind the condition and the definitions. So any $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ is an interior point of it and so $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, for open $O \subseteq Y$.

So the definitions are equivalent (the pure metric one and the topological one for the generated topologies), which sort of can be seen to justify either definition in terms of the other.